# I am getting delayed response inside the Prop which i am passing from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

i get Undefined value at this point routeHappyData.routeHappyData.upaData But when i console log it outside i can see the data coming after some time.How can i fix the delayed data before the code reaches this line let mainResp = routeHappyData.routeHappyData.upaData;

```
const getHealthAndSafetyContent = (routeHappyData) => {
            let photoid = [];
            let attributeHeadline = [];
            let attributeCaption = [];
            let smallPicture = [];
            let largePicture = [];
            let photoAttachmentId = [];
            let mainResp = routeHappyData.routeHappyData.upaData;
            console.log(mainResp)
            if (mainResp) {
                return mainResp.map(data => {
                    let requiredData = data.Response.included;
                    console.log(requiredData)
                    requiredData.map((item) => {
                        if (item.type === "upa" && (item.attributes.categories[0] === "brand" || item.attributes.categories[0] === "promotion")) {
                            photoAttachmentId.push(item.relationships.photo_attachments.data[0].id)
                            attributeHeadline.push(item.attributes.headline);                       
                        }
                        if (item.type === "photo_attachment") {
                            photoAttachmentId.map(x => {
                                if (item.id === x) {
                                    attributeCaption.push(item.attributes.caption)
                                    photoid.push(item.relationships.photo.data.id)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        if (item.type === "photo") {
                            photoid.map(z => {
                                if (item.id === z) {
                                    largePicture.push(item.attributes.large_url)
                                    smallPicture.push(item.attributes.thumb_url)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        return item
                    })
                    return data;
                })
            }
            return [];
        }
```

Comment: Could you please show us what routeHappyData.routeHappyData.upaData is?

Comment: routeHappyData is the data which i am passing as a prop to this component which contains routeHappydata as property name and in that property i have another nested property upadata